# Do certain operations on marked cells in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA programming. I think I have a simple question which I can't find a solution to by searching my self
I want to mark an arbitrary cell range and then call a macro that border the selected range this I have accomplished. Then I want to insert a calculation in the bottom left cell. But when I record a macro, it inserts the calculation in the same cell every time for instance G11. But since the before handed selection 
should be arbitrary it should not always insert the calculation in G11.

So consider I have marked A10:G11. Then I call a macro. And it should insert a calculation in G11.

If I then mark I1:O2. Then when I call the macro I want it to insert the calculation in 02.

Hope you get my point.

Thank you in advance

Christian Skjøth

Comment: Tick "Relative addresses" when recording the macro.

Comment: I get it so simpel thank you :)